Branching Rule for GL(n,q)
let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field of order $q$, I know that the irreducible representations of the general linear group $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is parametrized by partition-valued functions, I want to ask if there exists some branching rule (similar to $S_n$) when restricting the irreducible reps of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ to the special linear group $SL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$?
Thank you.
